# Python code stops outputting during/after print statement, but the same part of code works when isolated as its own program. What's going on?

Tags: python, hamming-code

I am trying to implement my own version of Hamming code with **even** parity (as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hamming-code-in-computer-network/), except **I'm starting counting the bits from left to right**, rather than right to left) in Python.

My code is as follows:

```
# Python program to demonstrate Hamming code
  
  
def calcCheckBits(m):
  
    # Use the formula 2 ^ r >= m + r + 1 to calculate the number of redundant bits.
    # Iterate over 0 ... m and return the value that satisfies the equation.
  
    for i in range(m):
        if(2**i >= m + i + 1):
            print("Number of redundant bits: " + str(i))
            return i


def posCheckBits(data, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to the power of 2.
    j = 0
    k = 1
    m = len(data)
    res = ''
  
    # If position is power of 2, then insert '0'; else, append the data.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            res = res + '0'
            print("check bit placed at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            j += 1
        else:
            res = res + data[k - 1]
            print("appending data at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            k += 1
    
    print("res: " + res)
    return res


def determineCheckBits(data, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to powers of 2.
    j = 0
    m = len(data)
    res = data
    activatedBitCounter = 0
  
    # If position i is a power of 2, then find the value of the check bit; else, do nothing.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            contributedToBy = [] # the bits that have i in their sum of powers of 2
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            # Find the values that i is contributed to by (that is, the values where i contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2)
            print("Now finding the values where " + str(i) + " contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.")
            for y in range(3, m + r + 1):
                powers = []
                z = 1
                while z <= y:
                    if z & y:
                        powers.append(z)
                        z <<= 1
                print("The list of powers is " + str(powers))
                print("The powers of 2 that sum to " + str(y) + " are ")
                for l in range(len(powers)):
                    print(powers[l])
                if(i in powers):
                    contributedToBy.append(y)
            print("The bits that have " + str(i) + " in their sum of powers of 2 are ")
            for l in range(len(contributedToBy)):
                print(contributedToBy[l])
            for l in contributedToBy:
                if(int(res[l - 1]) == 1):
                    activatedBitCounter += 1
            # Check if the number of activated bits is odd.
            # If so, then, since we want even parity, set the checkbit to 1; else, set to 0.
            if((activatedBitCounter % 2) != 0):
                res[i] = 1
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 1")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            else:
                res[i] = 0
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 0")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            activatedBitCounter = 0 # reset counter
            j += 1 # Append j by 1 to move onto next power
        else:
            print("else, position " + str(i) + " is not a power of 2, so res = " + res)
    
    print("Final res value from function determineCheckBits: " + res)
    return res


# Enter the data to be transmitted
data = '1100011' # codeword
print("data is: " + data)
  
# Calculate the number of parity bits required
m = len(data)
r = calcCheckBits(m)
  
# Determine the positions of check bits
arr = posCheckBits(data, r)

# Determine the check bits
arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)
```

The transmitted codeword in this case is 1100011.

Each bit whose ordinal position is a power of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8) is a check bit and forces the parity of some 'collection' of bits including itself. Parity may be forced to be either even or odd.

A data bit contributes to the parity of all the bits in its *decomposition into a sum of powers of 2*. For example:
3 = 2 + 1
7 = 4 + 2 + 1
11 = 8 + 2 + 1
Making a list of these:
1 is contributed to by 3, 5, 7, 9, 11
2 is contributed to by 3, 6, 7, 10, 11
4 is contributed to by 5, 6, 7
8 is contributed to by 9, 10, 11
We then put the data bits in their positions and calculate each check bit.
For example, for 1100011, using *even* parity:
[image]

1 is contributed to by 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, and if we look at these bits for check 1, we have a 1 at bits 3, 5, and 11, which is odd (1 + 1 + 1 = 3), so since we want even parity, we set the bit 1 to 1. Skipping to 8, we see that 8 is contributed to by 9, 10, 11, and if we look at these bits for check 4, we have a 1 at bits 10 and 11, which is even (1 + 1 = 2), so since want even parity, we set the bit 8 to 0. This is how we get 11111000011.

The code above should produce 11111000011 from the input 1100011.

As you can see in the code, I've added a bunch of print statements for debugging. The problem is that this python code just randomly stops outputting anything at

```
The powers of 2 that sum to 3 are 
1
2
```

as seen here:

[image]

It's just stuck there.

This is very perplexing, because if I execute only the part of the code that contains this print statement, it seems to work fine:

```
def testPowers(m, r):
# If position i is power of 2, then find the value of the parity bit; else, do nothing.
    j = 0
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            contributedToBy = [] # the bits that have i in their sum of powers of 2
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            # Find the values that i is contributed to by (that is, the values where i contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2)
            print("Now finding the values where " + str(i) + " contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.")
            for y in range(3, m + r + 1):
                powers = []
                z = 1
                while z <= y:
                    if z & y:
                        powers.append(z)
                    z <<= 1
                print("The powers of 2 that sum to " + str(y) + " are ")
                for l in range(len(powers)):
                    print(powers[l])
                if(i in powers):
                    contributedToBy.append(y)
            print("The bits that have " + str(i) + " in their sum of powers of 2 are ")
            for l in range(len(contributedToBy)):
                print(contributedToBy[l])
                
m = 7
r = 4
testPowers(m, r)
```

[image]
[image]

I've only just started learning Python, so I honestly have no idea what's going wrong. Why isn't my code working, and how do I fix it?

---

### EDIT1

I think I fixed the indentation error with `z <<= 1`, as Tim Roberts suggested, but now I get another error.

```
# Python program to demonstrate Hamming code
  
  
def calcCheckBits(m):
  
    # Use the formula 2 ^ r >= m + r + 1 to calculate the number of redundant bits.
    # Iterate over 0 ... m and return the value that satisfies the equation.
  
    for i in range(m):
        if(2**i >= m + i + 1):
            print("Number of redundant bits: " + str(i))
            return i


def posCheckBits(data, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to the power of 2.
    j = 0
    k = 1
    m = len(data)
    res = ''
  
    # If position is power of 2, then insert '0'; else, append the data.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            res = res + '0'
            print("check bit placed at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            j += 1
        else:
            res = res + data[k - 1]
            print("appending data at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            k += 1
    
    print("res: " + res)
    return res


def determineCheckBits(data, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to powers of 2.
    j = 0
    m = len(data)
    res = data
    activatedBitCounter = 0
  
    # If position i is a power of 2, then find the value of the check bit; else, do nothing.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            contributedToBy = [] # the bits that have i in their sum of powers of 2
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            # Find the values that i is contributed to by (that is, the values where i contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2)
            print("Now finding the values where " + str(i) + " contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.")
            for y in range(3, m + r + 1):
                powers = []
                z = 1
                while z <= y:
                    if z & y:
                        powers.append(z)
                    z <<= 1
                print("The list of powers is " + str(powers))
                print("The powers of 2 that sum to " + str(y) + " are ")
                for l in range(len(powers)):
                    print(powers[l])
                if(i in powers):
                    contributedToBy.append(y)
            print("The bits that have " + str(i) + " in their sum of powers of 2 are ")
            for l in range(len(contributedToBy)):
                print(contributedToBy[l])
            for l in contributedToBy:
                if(int(res[l - 1]) == 1):
                    activatedBitCounter += 1
            # Check if the number of activated bits is odd.
            # If so, then, since we want even parity, set the checkbit to 1; else, set to 0.
            if((activatedBitCounter % 2) != 0):
                res[i] = 1
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 1")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            else:
                res[i] = 0
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 0")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            activatedBitCounter = 0 # reset counter
            j += 1 # Append j by 1 to move onto next power
        else:
            print("else, position " + str(i) + " is not a power of 2, so res = " + res)
    
    print("Final res value from function determineCheckBits: " + res)
    return res


# Enter the data to be transmitted
data = '1100011' # codeword
print("data is: " + data)
  
# Calculate the number of parity bits required
m = len(data)
r = calcCheckBits(m)
  
# Determine the positions of check bits
arr = posCheckBits(data, r)

# Determine the check bits
arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)
```

Error:

```
appending data at position 11
res = 00101000011
res: 00101000011
If 1 == 1
Now finding the values where 1 contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.
The list of powers is [1, 2]
The powers of 2 that sum to 3 are 
1
2
The list of powers is [4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 4 are 
4
The list of powers is [1, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 5 are 
1
4
The list of powers is [2, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 6 are 
2
4
The list of powers is [1, 2, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 7 are 
1
2
4
The list of powers is [8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 8 are 
8
The list of powers is [1, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 9 are 
1
8
The list of powers is [2, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 10 are 
2
8
The list of powers is [1, 2, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 11 are 
1
2
8
The list of powers is [4, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 12 are 
4
8
The list of powers is [1, 4, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 13 are 
1
4
8
The list of powers is [2, 4, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 14 are 
2
4
8
The list of powers is [1, 2, 4, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 15 are 
1
2
4
8
The bits that have 1 in their sum of powers of 2 are 
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/testMultiParts.py", line 106, in <module>
    arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)
  File "/Users/x/testMultiParts.py", line 73, in determineCheckBits
    if(int(res[l - 1]) == 1):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Again, the other program doesn't have this error:

```
If 1 == 1
Now finding the values where 1 contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.
The powers of 2 that sum to 3 are 
1
2
The powers of 2 that sum to 4 are 
4
The powers of 2 that sum to 5 are 
1
4
The powers of 2 that sum to 6 are 
2
4
The powers of 2 that sum to 7 are 
1
2
4
The powers of 2 that sum to 8 are 
8
The powers of 2 that sum to 9 are 
1
8
The powers of 2 that sum to 10 are 
2
8
The powers of 2 that sum to 11 are 
1
2
8
The bits that have 1 in their sum of powers of 2 are 
3
5
7
9
11
```

---

### EDIT2

```
# Python program to demonstrate Hamming code
  
  
def calcCheckBits(m):
  
    # Use the formula 2 ^ r >= m + r + 1 to calculate the number of redundant bits.
    # Iterate over 0 ... m and return the value that satisfies the equation.
  
    for i in range(m):
        if(2**i >= m + i + 1):
            print("Number of redundant bits: " + str(i))
            return i


def posCheckBits(res, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to the power of 2.
    j = 0
    k = 1
    m = len(data)
    res = ''
  
    # If position is power of 2, then insert '0'; else, append the data.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            res = res + '0'
            print("check bit placed at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            j += 1
        else:
            res = res + data[k - 1]
            print("appending data at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            k += 1
    
    print("res: " + res)
    return res


def determineCheckBits(res, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to powers of 2.
    j = 0
    res = list(data)
    m = len(res)
    activatedBitCounter = 0
    
    print("At the beginning, res is " + str(res))
    print("At the beginning, m is " + str(m))
    # If position i is a power of 2, then find the value of the check bit; else, do nothing.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            contributedToBy = [] # the bits that have i in their sum of powers of 2
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            # Find the values that i is contributed to by (that is, the values where i contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2)
            print("Now finding the values where " + str(i) + " contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.")
            for y in range(3, m + r + 1):
                powers = []
                z = 1
                while z <= y:
                    if z & y:
                        powers.append(z)
                    z <<= 1
                print("The list of powers is " + str(powers))
                print("The powers of 2 that sum to " + str(y) + " are ")
                for l in range(len(powers)):
                    print(powers[l])
                if(i in powers):
                    contributedToBy.append(y)
            print("The bits that have " + str(i) + " in their sum of powers of 2 are ")
            for l in range(len(contributedToBy)):
                print(contributedToBy[l])
            for l in contributedToBy:
                if(int(res[l - 1]) == 1):
                    activatedBitCounter += 1
            # Check if the number of activated bits is odd.
            # If so, then, since we want even parity, set the checkbit to 1; else, set to 0.
            if((activatedBitCounter % 2) != 0):
                res[i] = '1'
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 1")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            else:
                res[i] = '0'
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 0")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            activatedBitCounter = 0 # reset counter
            j += 1 # Append j by 1 to move onto next power
        else:
            print("else, position " + str(i) + " is not a power of 2, so res = " ''.join(res))
    res = ''.join(res)
    print("Final res value from function determineCheckBits: " + res)
    return res


# Enter the data to be transmitted
data = '1100011' # codeword
print("data is: " + data)
  
# Calculate the number of parity bits required
m = len(data)
r = calcCheckBits(m)
  
# Determine the positions of check bits
arr = posCheckBits(data, r)

# Determine the check bits
arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)
```

Error:

```
res = 00101000011
res: 00101000011
At the beginning, res is ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
At the beginning, m is 7
If 1 == 1
Now finding the values where 1 contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.
The list of powers is [1, 2]
The powers of 2 that sum to 3 are 
1
2
The list of powers is [4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 4 are 
4
The list of powers is [1, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 5 are 
1
4
The list of powers is [2, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 6 are 
2
4
The list of powers is [1, 2, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 7 are 
1
2
4
The list of powers is [8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 8 are 
8
The list of powers is [1, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 9 are 
1
8
The list of powers is [2, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 10 are 
2
8
The list of powers is [1, 2, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 11 are 
1
2
8
The bits that have 1 in their sum of powers of 2 are 
3
5
7
9
11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/testMultiParts.py", line 108, in <module>
    arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)
  File "/Users/x/testMultiParts.py", line 75, in determineCheckBits
    if(int(res[l - 1]) == 1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

### EDIT3

Ok, I think I got it!

```
# Python program to demonstrate Hamming code
  
  
def calcCheckBits(m):
  
    # Use the formula 2 ^ r >= m + r + 1 to calculate the number of redundant bits.
    # Iterate over 0 ... m and return the value that satisfies the equation.
  
    for i in range(m):
        if(2**i >= m + i + 1):
            print("Number of redundant bits: " + str(i))
            return i


def posCheckBits(res, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to the power of 2.
    j = 0
    k = 1
    m = len(data)
    res = ''
  
    # If position is power of 2, then insert '0'; else, append the data.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            res = res + '0'
            print("check bit placed at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            j += 1
        else:
            res = res + data[k - 1]
            print("appending data at position " + str(i))
            print("res = " + res)
            k += 1
    
    print("res: " + res)
    return res


def determineCheckBits(arr, r):
  
    # Check bits are placed at the positions that correspond to powers of 2.
    j = 0
    res = list(arr)
    m = len(data)
    activatedBitCounter = 0
    
    print("At the beginning, res is " + str(res))
    print("At the beginning, m is " + str(m))
    # If position i is a power of 2, then find the value of the check bit; else, do nothing.
    for i in range(1, m + r + 1):
        if(i == 2**j):
            contributedToBy = [] # the bits that have i in their sum of powers of 2
            print("If " + str(i) + " == " + str(2**j))
            # Find the values that i is contributed to by (that is, the values where i contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2)
            print("Now finding the values where " + str(i) + " contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.")
            for y in range(3, m + r + 1):
                powers = []
                z = 1
                while z <= y:
                    if z & y:
                        powers.append(z)
                    z <<= 1
                print("The list of powers is " + str(powers))
                print("The powers of 2 that sum to " + str(y) + " are ")
                for l in range(len(powers)):
                    print(powers[l])
                if(i in powers):
                    contributedToBy.append(y)
            print("The bits that have " + str(i) + " in their sum of powers of 2 are ")
            for l in range(len(contributedToBy)):
                print(contributedToBy[l])
            for l in contributedToBy:
                print("contributedToBy is " + str(contributedToBy))
                print("res is " + str(res))
                print("res[l - 1] is " + res[l - 1])
                if(int(res[l - 1]) == 1):
                    activatedBitCounter += 1
            # Check if the number of activated bits is odd.
            # If so, then, since we want even parity, set the checkbit to 1; else, set to 0.
            if((activatedBitCounter % 2) != 0):
                res[i - 1] = '1'
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 1")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            else:
                res[i - 1] = '0'
                print("activatedBitCounter is " + str(activatedBitCounter) + " so set bit " + str(i) + " of res to 0")
                print("res is now " + str(res))
            activatedBitCounter = 0 # reset counter
            j += 1 # Append j by 1 to move onto next power
        else:
            print("else, position " + str(i) + " is not a power of 2, so res = " ''.join(res))
    res = ''.join(res)
    print("Final res value from function determineCheckBits: " + res)
    return res


# Enter the data to be transmitted
data = '1100011' # codeword
print("data is: " + data)
  
# Calculate the number of parity bits required
m = len(data)
r = calcCheckBits(m)
  
# Determine the positions of check bits
arr = posCheckBits(data, r)

# Determine the check bits
arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)
```

Output:

```
res = 00101000011
res: 00101000011
At the beginning, res is ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
At the beginning, m is 7
If 1 == 1
Now finding the values where 1 contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.
The list of powers is [1, 2]
The powers of 2 that sum to 3 are 
1
2
```

... skip to `8 == 8`:

```
If 8 == 8
Now finding the values where 8 contributes to its decomposition into a sum of powers of 2.
The list of powers is [1, 2]
The powers of 2 that sum to 3 are 
1
2
The list of powers is [4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 4 are 
4
The list of powers is [1, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 5 are 
1
4
The list of powers is [2, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 6 are 
2
4
The list of powers is [1, 2, 4]
The powers of 2 that sum to 7 are 
1
2
4
The list of powers is [8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 8 are 
8
The list of powers is [1, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 9 are 
1
8
The list of powers is [2, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 10 are 
2
8
The list of powers is [1, 2, 8]
The powers of 2 that sum to 11 are 
1
2
8
The bits that have 8 in their sum of powers of 2 are 
8
9
10
11
contributedToBy is [8, 9, 10, 11]
res is ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
res[l - 1] is 0
contributedToBy is [8, 9, 10, 11]
res is ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
res[l - 1] is 0
contributedToBy is [8, 9, 10, 11]
res is ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
res[l - 1] is 1
contributedToBy is [8, 9, 10, 11]
res is ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
res[l - 1] is 1
activatedBitCounter is 2 so set bit 8 of res to 0
res is now ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
else, position 91 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1
else, position 101 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1
else, position 111 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 0 is not a power of 2, so res = 1 is not a power of 2, so res = 1
Final res value from function determineCheckBits: 11111000011
```

And so we have 11111000011, as required!

---

### EDIT4

I cleaned up the last part by changing it back to

```
else:
            print("else, position " + str(i) + " is not a power of 2, so res = " + str(res))
```

This seems to clean up the output:

```
res is now ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
else, position 9 is not a power of 2, so res = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
else, position 10 is not a power of 2, so res = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
else, position 11 is not a power of 2, so res = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
Final res value from function determineCheckBits: 11111000011
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself.  When you Ctrl-C to terminate the program, did you notice where it was looping?

```
The list of powers is [1, 2]
The powers of 2 that sum to 3 are 
1
2
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 107, in <module>
    arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)
  File "x.py", line 60, in determineCheckBits
    while z <= y:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If you'll look at that loop, you'll see that `z` never increments, so it loops forever.  That's because line 63:

```
    z <<= 1
```

is indented in one too many indents.  If you fix that, it moves on.  It does eventually get a different error, but that will be for another question.

**EDIT**
Other problems.  In `determineCheckBits`, you are treating `res` as if it is a list of ints, trying to assign elements by index.  It is not, it is a string.  So, at the beginning, change:

```
    res = data
```

to

```
    res = list(data)
```

Towards the bottom, change

```
        res[i] = 1
```

to

```
        res[i] = '1'
```

and do the same 4 lines later with 0.  Then, change the last 5 lines to:

```
        else:
            print("else, position " + str(i) + " is not a power of 2, so res = " + ''.join(res))
    
    res = ''.join(res)
    print("Final res value from function determineCheckBits: " + res)
    return res
```

and I think you will have happiness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I fixed the problem with `z <<= 1`, but now I'm getting an `IndexError` that the other program isn't. Please see my edit.

Comment: `res` is 11 elements long, but you're trying to reference element 15.   Do you need to pad `res`?  Or do you want to protect it with `if l < len(res):`?

Comment: By the way, `if` statements in Python do not need parentheses.  That's a C habit.

Comment: You have other problems.  You are treating `res` like a list of integers, but it's actually a string.  I'll modify the post with other edits.

Comment: I'm trying to find where it's getting to 15. It should be at most 11. As I mentioned in my example, if I input 1100011, then the output should be 11111000011.

Comment: `m` is 11, `r` is 4, so `m+r+1` is 16.

Comment: Also, you are counting your bits backwards.  You have `res[i]` to set bit i, but arrays count from the left, not the right.  Try `res[-i-1]`.

Comment: I have changed it to `def determineCheckBits(res, r):`, `m = len(res)`, `res = list(data)`, and calling it with `arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)`. So now `m` should be 7 and `res` should be 11, so that m + r = 7 + 4 = 11. This means that m + r + 1 = 12 for counting purposes, since we start counting at 1 and want to end at 11 in some of these loops, such as `range(1, m + r + 1)`.

Comment: With regards to `res[i]`, don't we want to count from left to right? Remember my implementation is trying to count from left to right.

Comment: No, `m` is still 11.  You added 4 bits to it in `arr = posCheckBits(data,r)`.

Comment: Oh, I fixed the m to 7. I swapped the variables declarations around, so that we first have `res = list(data)` and *then* have `m = lens(res)` afterwards. The function definition is `def determineCheckBits(res, r):` and we are calling it with `arr = determineCheckBits(arr, r)`. At the beginning, res is `['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']`, and m is 7 (according to my added print statements).

Comment: Ok, that part is fixed: The bits that have 1 in their sum of powers of 2 are 
3
5
7
9
11. Now I'm getting `if(int(res[l - 1]) == 1): IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: But don't you want `res` as passed in to `determineCheckBits` to already have ROOM for those check bits?  `determine` doesn't make the string longer.  It just shoves bits in.  I've now lost track of what your source looks like, so I can't follow along.

Answer (score 2):

Would you be upset if I did this in 28 lines?

```
data = '1100011'

bits = list(int(i) for i in data)
print(bits)

outbits = []
for i in range(1,99):
    if bin(i).count('1') == 1:
        outbits.append(0)
    else:
        outbits.append(bits.pop(0))
    if not bits:
        break

bits = outbits
print(bits)

ii = 1
while ii < len(bits):
    sumx = 0
    for i in range(len(bits)):
        if i != ii-1 and (i+1) & ii:
            sumx ^= bits[i]
    bits[ii-1] = sumx
    ii <<= 1

print(bits)
```